# SQL Server: Select all but the first result in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an issue with two tables, let's call them Item and ItemStatuses.  We track each change to the status, so there is a start date and end date in the ItemStatuses table.  We track the current status by looking for the one with an end date that is null.

Through an error in the system the newest status was added multiple times to a number of items.  I need to select all but the first status for each item.  I have the following query which gives me all the open statuses.  I was trying this route because I figured I could use the row number to skip the first one, but there are multiple Items in these sets, so I need to skip the first status for each item.  I think I'm pretty close with my query, but I'm not sure what I need to do.

```
SELECT ID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ItemID)
FROM ItemStatuses WHERE ID IN
(
SELECT
s.ID
FROM Items as i
INNER JOIN ItemStatuses AS s ON
i.ID = s.ItemID AND
s.EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY i.ID
HAVING COUNT(i.ID) > 1
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you looking to update the rows apart from the first?

Comment: @ChrisBint Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @tq If you put that as an answer I'll accept it, that's the route I'll take.

Comment: Use `partition by` to identify the "newest" over multiple items: `row_number()over(partition by id order by Enddate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify your `SQL` query since this can become overly complicated and expensive.
Then use your server sided language to perform any filtering or condition.

Comment: -1 - this is the *wrong* way to go about things in the general case. The **majority** of the time the database can be faster than your application code.  That being said, there are exceptions to this rule ... this is not one of those cases however.

Comment: @SeanVieira i see, i pictured `joins` being implemented

Comment: For my purposes here I only have a few to deal with and I think I might just use LINQ to do my manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate how to update *all but the first status* of your table:

```
declare @itemstatuses table (id int, Enddate datetime, theStatus int)
insert into @itemstatuses
    values  (1,getdate()-3,1),(1,getdate()-2,2),(1,getdate()-1,3),
            (2,getdate()-3,2),(2,getdate()-2,2),(2,getdate()-1,99),
            (3,getdate(),1)

select 'before',* from @itemStatuses

;with sorted
as  (   
        select  [r] = row_number()over(partition by id order by Enddate), * 
        from    @ItemStatuses
    )
update sorted
set theStatus = 100
where r>1

select 'after',* from @itemStatuses
```